# install pydelicious with pip on python3.4

Tags: pip, python-3.4

I got this error while using

```
pip install pydelicious
```

> "Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pydelicious. Some externally >hosted filed were ignored .
>   Cleaning up...
>   No distributions at all found for pydelicious"

However when I tried:
    pip search pydelicious

I got a match:

> "pydelicious - Access delicious.com API's with Python"

Why can't I install the package even though it pops up in pip search?

Answer (score 4):

Try this, it worked for me:

```
sudo pip install pydelicious --allow-external pydelicious --allow-unverified pydelicious
```

The `--allow-external` argument allows pip to get and install files that are not hosted by pip, and the `--allow-unverified` argument allows files to be installed by pip that have not been verified. Type in the code exactly as above in the command line and it will execute and install pydelicious as needed.

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer more please?

Comment: The --allow-external attribute allows pip to get and install files that are not hosted by pip, and the --allow-unverified attribute allows files to be installed by pip that have not been verified. Type in the code exactly as above in the command line and it will execute and install pydelicious as needed.

Comment: Forgot to add "by editing your answer". ;-) Done that for you, thx for the explanation.

Comment: `Collecting pydelicious
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pydelicious (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pydelicious`  It can't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can also install using conda if you have anaconda version, Here is what you can do

```
anaconda search -t conda pydelicious
```

and then use

```
conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/derickl pydelicious
```